# Is there a better way to write a Typescript XML parser than using PropTypes?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm working on the architecture of a web application that will need to consume SOAP APIs in hundreds, if not thousands of places. Each of these will be written by one of 200-300 developers over several years. Knowing the scale of this task and what how many people are going to work on it I'm trying to make interacting with this SOAP API via Typescript as painless as possible.

I don't want every developer to have to convert a lot of strings into their correct types in every place that we make a request to this API, so I want to do the conversion for them. Unfortunately because Typescript cannot reflect this has proved a little difficult. I'm having to use a PropTypes approach.

But this means duplicating the definition of the structure, because it must be available in both the TS type ("type space" / compile-time) and the proptypes ("value space" / run-time). Omitting some of the implementation for brevity (a simple recursive algorithm using DOMParser), I've come up with this sort of solution using the `prop-types` package:

```
declare type User = {
  'UserId': number
  'UserName': string
  'UserType': number
}

const propTypes = {
  "User.UserId": PropTypes.number,
  'User.UserName': PropTypes.string,
  "User.UserType": PropTypes.number
}

describe('XMLParser', () => {
  const GET_USERS_RESPONSE_3_USERS = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
      '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">\n' +
      '   <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n' +
      '      <return>\n' +
      '         <Users>\n' +
      '            <User>\n' +
      '               <UserId>9131</UserId>\n' +
      '               <UserType>2</UserType>\n' +
      '               <UserName>Cline, Erin</UserName>\n' +
      '            </User>\n' +
      '            <User>\n' +
      '               <UserId>9130</UserId>\n' +
      '               <UserType>2</UserType>\n' +
      '               <UserName>Dalton, Gail</UserName>\n' +
      '            </User>\n' +
      '            <User>\n' +
      '               <UserId>9129</UserId>\n' +
      '               <UserType>2</UserType>\n' +
      '               <UserName>Duran, Chris</UserName>\n' +
      '            </User>\n' +
      '         </Users>\n' +
      '         <status>success</status>\n' +
      '      </return>\n' +
      '   </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n' +
      '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'

  it('should return an array with three users when passed a selector with 3 matches', () => {
    const parser = new XMLParser(GET_USERS_RESPONSE_3_USERS, propTypes)
    const result = parser.parseXMLData('User')
    const expected = [{
          "UserId": 9131,
          "UserName": "Cline, Erin",
          "UserType": 2,
        },
        {
          "UserId": 9130,
          "UserName": "Dalton, Gail",
          "UserType": 2,
        },
        {
          "UserId": 9129,
          "UserName": "Duran, Chris",
          "UserType": 2,
        }
      ]
    expect(result).toEqual(expected)
  })

class XMLParser {

  public constructor(data: string, private readonly propTypes: { [key: string] : Requireable<number | string>; }) {
    //...
  }

  public parseXMLData<T>(tag: string): T[] {
    //...
  }
}
```

I think this is about as nice as it will be possible to get without reflection. But I am concerned about there being two different definitions of the `User` type that could diverge. And as I'm new to Typescript, I'm wondering if there are any more conventional/intuitive Typescript ways to solve this problem that I may have missed?

Comment: what is `PropTypes`? Is it an Enum?

Comment: It comes from the `prop-types` package from the React team: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

It could just as well have been any other type, but I figured for correctness it was best to use this package which should accurately reflect all the possible ES6 types (and supports some fancier stuff like unions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something that can help you:

```js
type RenameProp<
  T extends string, 
  S extends string
> = T extends `${S}${infer Substring}` ? Substring : never

type TransformToType<T, S extends string> = { 
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? RenameProp<K, S> : never]: T[K] 
}

type User = TransformToType<typeof propTypes, 'User.'>

/*
    type User = {
        'UserId': number
        'UserName': string
        'UserType': number
    }
*/
```

We can use the object `propTypes` to construct another type `User`. As `T` we supply the `typeof propTypes` and as `S` a substring which should be removed from the start of the property names, in this case `'User.'`.

The problem here might be the `prop-types` package. From here I can't find out if `typeof PropTypes.number` will actually resolve to `number`.

---

**Edit:**

I just saw that `PropTypes` are nested in `Requireable`. We can also extract that:

```
type RenameProp<
  T extends string, 
  S extends string
> = T extends `${S}${infer Substring}` ? Substring : never

type ExtractRequireable<T> = T extends Requireable<infer S> ? S : never

type TransformToType<T, S extends string> = { 
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? RenameProp<K, S> : never]: ExtractRequireable<T[K]> 
}

type User = TransformToType<typeof propTypes, 'User.'>
```

The type of `User` is now exactly how you specified in your question.

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FAehAIAcCcHtILQBcCekCmBncBbWBjAa2GFQ3ACV0BHAVwEtp0BDAIwBt0AeAFQD5wAXnA8SnJOAB2tHK3TQAXJRoMmbTl2mz5A4QAYA3MHHhMSaPUkBzJVTqMWHbmYvXd4AEQejwfLElm4AAKcJA8aFhC4ADewOBSMnLQADSm5pZWwAC%20JKAQZszQSCR%20ARIw8OEY2MKx8R4AqpjyAHRN8gCSACYeSiGVEZgtWknJceAA5O3Qbc3QAHLMOOgTfaFVWC0uGWP107PyG73B64PDifLZJGToypJL6P2QXOM84OgAHkjokl3Y29ZUuMAMrvL4-P5pVyZdxvT7fX7YAAGABJosCsmjLAAzeTgYG0VgAqxZJHgAD8%20MJxPASkk6AAbpdSBFwABRL7QZj4JB2VSODT8KJw8GI5T2NROLg4vHAgSU0F0xnMm4iLkBbGwaA4HiwDa8VKg%20EQ-7pNxRaLgcYAbQA0uBLOBCOgULBsSJwMxsPbjWKaZSqPdlk8uLbDQIlUzoABdJQc8zc3kqBzqbg8O3RgRXFnkabC9WYTXa3X6m5uqCnaqpKZzFoTPgkEAAKnG8VVedqrfi3ZrnS6qwS2mgXe7k2mi2WA%20JI570w2A5Gl1HOSbICAA)